# Hydrogen Peroxide Heat of Dilution

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, thermodynamics, aqueous-solution

Based on some data [here](http://www.h2o2.com/technical-library/physical-chemical-properties/thermodynamic-properties/default.aspx?pid=37&name=Heat-of-Dilution), I am getting the heat of dilution of 100% $\ce{H2O2}$ as approx. 1100 cal/mole.

[image]

That's about 4.6 kJ/mol if I did my math right.

Is this a correct value? Seems too low to me.

e.g. For the corresponding heat of dilution for $\ce{HCl}$ I get 74.8 kJ/mol from Wikipedia.

Comment: HCl dissociates into ions which both needs solvatation; in short, HCl reacts with water quite fiercely. On the contrary, H2O2 just sits there and does nothing, except for a few relatively insignificant hydrogen bonds. So no, the huge difference is not unexpected.